# Convert array of array into array of object with custom keys- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a **array of array** received from an endpoint and I want it to be converted into **array of object**. My array looks like bellow,

```js
{
  "results": [
    [
      "ASIA",
      "INDIA",
      "2003",
      "Type 1",
      "Group 1",
      "Division 1"
    ],
    [
      "AFRICA",
      "Nigeria",
      "2004",
      "Type 2",
      "Group 2",
      "Division 2"
    ]
}
```

Code I have tried so far :

```js
let finalArr = [];

  var objs = data.results.map((val) => {
    finalArr.push(Object.assign({}, val));
  });

console.log("Converted into Array of Object",finalArr)
```

The above code returns array of object with keys as 0,1,2,3 but ,I would like my array object to have custom keys and expected output is :

```js
[
    {
      Region: "ASIA",
      Country: "INDIA",
      Year: "2004",
      Type: "Type 1",
      Group: "Group 1",
      Divison: "Division 1",
    },
    {
      Region: "AFRICA",
      Country: "Nigeria",
      Year: "2003",
      Type: "Type 2",
      Group: "Group 2",
      Divison: "Division 2",
    },
  ];
```

Comment: your attempt has an error `"ReferenceError: data is not defined",` also, your data is invalid syntax

Comment: @JaromandaX data is first array of array i have mentioned above , I am mapping on it

Comment: the data you've presented won't parse - so of course your code won't run - fix the syntax errors (missing `]` and a missing `"`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have corrected the syntax , Thanks but what i am looking for is custom keys not 0,1,2 keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the map function like this:

```js
  const data = {
    results: [
      ["ASIA", "INDIA", "2003", "Type 1", "Group 1", "Division 1"],
      ["AFRICA", "Nigeria", "2004", "Type 2", "Group 2", "Division 2"]
    ]
  };
  const finalArr = data.results.map((el) => ({
    Region: el[0],
    Country: el[1],
    Year: el[2],
    Type: el[3],
    Group: el[4],
    Divison: el[5]
  }));
  console.log(finalArr);
```

or with custom keys:

```js
  const customKeys = ["Region", "Country", "Year", "Type", "Group", "Division"];
  const data = {
    results: [
      ["ASIA", "INDIA", "2003", "Type 1", "Group 1", "Division 1"],
      ["AFRICA", "Nigeria", "2004", "Type 2", "Group 2", "Division 2"]
    ]
  };
  const finalArr = data.results.map((el) => {
    const obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) {
      obj[customKeys[i]] = el[i];
    }
    return obj;
  });
  console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code

```
let keys = ["Region", "Country", "Year", "Type", "Group", "Division"];

const result = [
  ["ASIA", "INDIA", "2003", "Type 1", "Group 1", "Division 1"],
  ["AFRICA", "Nigeria", "2004", "Type 2", "Group 2", "Division 2"]
];


let final = [];

result.forEach(elem => {
  let obj = {}
  elem.forEach((param,i )=> {
      obj[keys[i]] = param
  });
  final.push(obj)
});


console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This boss. If you are sure the data returned is in the right order of the country and so on

```
let finalArr = [];

  var objs = data.results.map((val) => {
     const obj = {
      Region: val[0],
      Country: val[1],
      Year: val[2],
      Type: val[3],
      Group: val[4],
      Divison: val[5],
    }
    return obj
  });
finalArray = objs
```

Since the returned values are in the array, It okay to get those return values using there indices

Answer (score 0):

using Object.fromEntries and an array of `key`s makes this trivial

```js
const data = {results: [["ASIA", "INDIA", "2003", "Type 1", "Group 1", "Division 1"],["AFRICA", "Nigeria", "2004", "Type 2", "Group 2", "Division 2"]]};

const keys = ["Region", "Cuntry", "Year", "Type", "Group", "Division"];
const result = data.results.map((el) =>
  Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => [key, el[i]]))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, For example:

```
let arrs = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
];

let objs = arrs.map(x => ({ 
  key1: x[0], 
  key2: x[1] 
}));

console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is dynamic solution with custom keys.
```

```js
const data = [
  [
    "ASIA",
    "INDIA",
    "2003",
    "Type 1",
    "Group 1",
    "Division 1"
  ],
  [
    "AFRICA",
    "Nigeria",
    "2004",
    "Type 2",
    "Group 2",
    "Division 2"
  ],
];
const keys = ["Region", "Country", "Year", "Type", "Group", "Division"];

const finalArr = data.map((item) => {
  const _obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
    _obj[keys[i]] = item[i];
  }
  return _obj;
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "results": [
    [
      "ASIA",
      "INDIA",
      "2003",
      "Type 1",
      "Group 1",
      "Division 1"
    ],
    [
      "AFRICA",
      "Nigeria",
      "2004",
      "Type 2",
      "Group 2",
      "Division 2"
    ]
  ]
};

//custom keys array 
let keys = ["Region", "Country", "Year", "Type", "Group", "Division"];

let finalArr = data.results.map((obj) => {
  //create array of key and value map for each object
  let keyValMap = keys.map((k, i) => [k, obj[i]]);
  return Object.fromEntries(keyValMap);
});

console.log("Converted into Array of Object", finalArr)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Try with below code snippet

```
const data =  [
      ["ASIA", "INDIA", "2003", "Type 1", "Group 1", "Division 1"],
      ["AFRICA", "Nigeria", "2004", "Type 2", "Group 2", "Division 2"]
    ]
  
  const expectedOutput = data.map((el,i) => ({
    Region: el[i],
    Country: el[i],
    Year: el[i],
    Type: el[i],
    Group: el[i],
    Divison: el[i]
  }));
  console.log(expectedOutput);
```